# What is a typical delay between harvesting honeydew and getting Attract Flowers in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

What is a typical delay between harvesting honeydew and getting Attract Flowers in Flutter?

There are rumors of a pattern, but I was never able to experimentally confirm one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to be 3 hours.

People who used Game Guru and similar tools posted on the forums that setting 3 hours (10800 seconds) to 1 second; you get the flowers 1 second after harvesting honeydew.